# Can I test autocorrelation from the generalized least squares model?

Tags: r, regression, correlation, least-squares, panel-data

I am trying to use a generalized least square model (`gls` in R) on my panel data to deal with autocorrelation problem. 
I do not want to have any lags for any variables.

I am trying to use Durbin-Watson test (`dwtest` in R) to check the autocorrelation problem from my generalized least square model (`gls`). 
However, I find that the `dwtest` is not applicable over `gls` function while it is applicable to other functions such as `lm`.

Is there a way to check the autocorrelation problem from my `gls` model?

Comment: Can anybody help me out with this question please????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Durbin-Watson test is designed to check for presence of autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Watson_statistic) in standard least-squares models (such as one fitted by `lm`). If autocorrelation is detected, one can then capture it explicitly in the model using, for example, generalized least squares (`gls` in R). My understanding is that Durbin-Watson is not appropriate to then test for "goodness of fit" in the resulting models, as `gls` residuals may no longer follow the same distribution as residuals from the standard `lm` model. (Somebody with deeper knowledge of statistics should correct me, if I'm wrong).

With that said, function `durbinWatsonTest` from the `car` package will accept arbitrary residuals and return the associated test statistic. You can therefore do something like this:

```
v <- gls( ... )$residuals
attr(v,"std") <- NULL      # get rid of the additional attribute
car::durbinWatsonTest( v )
```

Note that `durbinWatsonTest` will compute p-values only for `lm` models (likely due to the considerations described above), but you can estimate them empirically by permuting your data / residuals.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I was looking for! It was great!